# return updated object in xsodata update operation exit

Tags: odata, hana, hana-xs

I was wondering if it was possible in **SAP HANA** to update an entity with an **xsjslib** file and return the updated object. Currently, when updating an entry, it returns **'204 - No Content'**.

**Sample of xsodata**

```
"DEMO.VIEWS::myEntity" as "MyEntity" keys("ID")
create using "DEMO.SCRIPTS:createEntity.xsjslib::createEntry"
update using "DEMO.SCRIPTS:updateEntity.xsjslib::updateEntry"
delete using "DEMO.SCRIPTS:deleteEntity.xsjslib::deleteEntry";
```

**Response**

[image: no content]

**Useful documentation**

I've looked at the documentation SAP has on this and I don't seem to find anything related to updating.

[SAP documentation](https://help.sap.com/viewer/4505d0bdaf4948449b7f7379d24d0f0d/2.0.02/en-US/03735142bfd647c2a016fcd9359f3348.html)

There is also a great tutorial which explains this for the **create operation**. This works but sadly not for the update operation.

[Tutorial for create operation](https://blogs.sap.com/2015/09/21/how-to-return-generated-value-in-xsodata-using-xsjslib-modification-exit/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An HTTP PUT (or HTTP PATCH) has no response (check this for instance [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/PUT)). SAP does not change that standardized behavior.
So if you really need to get back the updated object (because for instance on backend side, some special logic changes properties not part of your PUT request), you have to do an additional GET request.

Comment: Actually, the standard says, that returning the patched instance of the entity is optional, so SAP would still conform to the spec, if they opted for above *safer* solution.

Comment: What makes things worse, is an SAP system where changes are implemented by canceling the existing instance and creating a new, changed one. With OData, there is no means to properly model that.
PATCH would work, it it returned an instance. Now, there is no way to know the primary key of the newly created instance.

Comment: @osxdirk What do you want to say us with your comments to a one year old post??